# YouTupe API V3, youtube.playlistItems.list, Parameters id vs playlistId

Tags: api, parameters, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to figure out what the difference between parameter `id` and `playlistId` is. According to the documentation or dev console respectively it is as this:

- `id`

  - *string* The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the playlist item.
  - The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more unique playlist item IDs. (string)
- `snippet.playlistId`

  - *string* The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the playlist that the playlist item is in.
  - The playlistId parameter specifies the unique ID of the playlist for which you want to retrieve playlist items. Note that even though this is an optional parameter, every request to retrieve playlist items must specify a value for either the id parameter or the playlistId parameter. (string)

This is what I try:

1. When I put my list ID of interest into the `id` field, I get a response but no items.
2. When I put my list ID of interest into the `playlistId` field, I get a response and all items.
3. When I put an item (i.e. video) ID into the `id` field I get a playlist back which includes that item (this playlist is mine as is the OAuth key) while some foreign video which is in a playlist for sure, I get an empty respone.

Can someone please clarify the meaning of `id` and `playlistId` in the API call `youtube.playlistItems.list`

Answer (score 0):

For every playlist YouTube gives an unique id called PlaylistID. In the playlist there are multiple videos attached to it those are called playlist items, for each and every playlist item YouTube provides again an unique id for them.

Here
id = Playlist Item ID

playlistId = playlist ID

playlist Item ID starts with "PLit" for example

Playlist Item ID : PLitbTaXZ_twddlko1LGJR4Y07holnfacEkLljtSgG2Mc

where as playlist id starts with "PLEv" for eample

Playlist ID : PLEv-m2yWNXmT0hYVtCL-52NhDTztewxz9

Comment: What about if playlist - id start with "PLU"

Answer (score 0):

so there are two optional parameters: "id" or "playListId". The original question was about "id" being a comma separated list ... of what? turns out its a comma separated list of play list item ids. So if your play list has three videos, and their ids are "A", "B" and "c" then "id=A,B" will return them just the two videos, whose ids are "A" or "B". In fact, if you wrote "id=A,B,BozoTheClown" and BozoTheClown is a valid id on ANY playlist, then your playlistQuery will include BozoTheClown listing along with the other two, A and B.

here's an example of what I mean: [BozoLikeQuery](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?maxResults=25&part=snippet,contentDetails&id=UExCQ0YyREFDNkZGQjU3NERFLjU5NzE2QkNERURDRTE5NDc=,UEx2aGtLMTgyN05Eejg0T08wWHo1MFZQYjRtWmJjTzgxRS4yODlGNEE0NkRGMEEzMEQy&key=AIzaSyDPC61pNwGSNWeBFZFnuxMJ1ksH3uR_qG8) 
[[image]youtube-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-api)[youtube-api-v3](/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3)